# Change default font size of Customer Portal

Tags: customer-portal, css

Is there a way I can change the default font size used in the Customer Portal?
From looking at my Firefox inspector the default sizes are in portal.css, do we have access to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this help page on [Customizing Your Self-Service Fonts and Colors](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=css_editor.htm&language=en_US) for instructions on changing font sizes, etc.